# Compare contents of two files line by line

Tags: android, file

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    FileOutputStream fos;
    FileInputStream fOne, fTwo;
    ArrayList<String> arr1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> arr2 = new ArrayList<String>();

    ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> wordsTwo = new ArrayList<String>();
    int count = 0;
    int countTwo = 0;
    int countThree = 0;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button  fileOne = (Button)findViewById(R.id.file1);
        Button  fileTwo = (Button)findViewById(R.id.file2);
        Button  compare = (Button)findViewById(R.id.compare);
        arr1.add("1");
        arr1.add("2");
        arr1.add("3");
        arr1.add("4");
        //arr1.add("3");

        arr2.add("1");
        arr2.add("2");


        fileOne.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                try
                {
                    fos = openFileOutput("File1", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

                    for(int temp = 0; temp< arr1.size(); temp++)
                    {
                        fos.write((arr1.get(temp).getBytes()) );
                        fos.write(System.getProperty("line.separator").getBytes());

                    }
                    fos.close();
                    fos.flush();

                }

                catch(Exception e)
                {

                }
            }
        });


        fileTwo.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                try
                {
                    fos = openFileOutput("File2", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

                    for(int temp = 0; temp< arr2.size(); temp++)
                    {
                        fos.write((arr2.get(temp).getBytes()) );
                        fos.write(System.getProperty("line.separator").getBytes());

                    }
                    fos.close();
                    fos.flush();

                }

                catch(Exception e)
                {

                }
            }
        });

        compare.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                try
                {
                    fOne = openFileInput("File1");
                    fTwo = openFileInput("File2");
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Scanner scanFile = new Scanner(new DataInputStream(fOne));
                Scanner scanFileT = new Scanner(new DataInputStream(fTwo));
                words = new ArrayList<String>();
                wordsTwo = new ArrayList<String>();

                while (scanFile.hasNextLine())
                {
                    if(scanFile.nextLine()!=null)
                    {
                        count++;
                    }

                    while(scanFileT.hasNextLine())
                    {
                        if(scanFileT.nextLine()!=null)
                        {
                            countTwo++;

                        }
                    }
                }

                try 
                {
                    fOne.close();
                    fTwo.close();
                    scanFile.close();
                    scanFileT.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "One : " + count, 1000).show();
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Two : " + countTwo, 1000).show();
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Three : " + countThree, 1000).show();
                count = 0 ;                         
                countTwo = 0;
                countThree = 0;
            }
        });
    }



}
```

Above is the code to write and read the file. What I did here, write two files and read the contents..Now I have to compare contents of files line by line. What needs to be done?

Comment: Means, you need to check file and where contents are not matched, you want to print that lines?

Comment: ya...I have to match contents...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following code. This will give you desired output. I took files from asset directory. So you need to replace that line of code if you are taking files from other directory.

```
private void compareFiles() throws Exception {

    String s1 = "";
    String s2 = "", s3 = "", s4 = "";
    String y = "", z = "";

    // Reading the contents of the files
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            getAssets().open("first.txt")));
    BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            getAssets().open("second.txt")));

    while ((z = br1.readLine()) != null) {
        s3 += z;
        s3 += System.getProperty("line.separator");
    }

    while ((y = br.readLine()) != null) {
        s1 += y;
        s1 += System.getProperty("line.separator");
    }

    // String tokenizing
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(s1);
    String[] a = new String[10000];
    for (int l = 0; l < 10000; l++) {
        a[l] = "";
    }
    int i = 0;
    while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
        s2 = st.nextToken();
        a[i] = s2;
        i++;
    }

    StringTokenizer st1 = new StringTokenizer(s3);
    String[] b = new String[10000];
    for (int k = 0; k < 10000; k++) {
        b[k] = "";
    }
    int j = 0;
    while (st1.hasMoreTokens()) {
        s4 = st1.nextToken();
        b[j] = s4;
        j++;
    }

    // comparing the contents of the files and printing the differences, if
    // any.
    int x = 0;
    for (int m = 0; m < a.length; m++) {
        if (a[m].equals(b[m])) {
        } else {
            x++;
            Log.d("Home", a[m] + " -- " + b[m]);
        }
    }
    Log.d("Home", "No. of differences : " + x);
    if (x > 0) {
        Log.d("Home", "Files are not equal");
    } else {
        Log.d("Home", "Files are equal. No difference found");
    }
}
```

**Input File 1**

1. Hi
2. Hello
3. Chintan
4. Rathod

**Input File 2**

1. Hi
2. HellO
3. Chintan
4. RathoD

**Output**

08-26 12:07:58.219: DEBUG/Home(2350): Hello3. -- HellO3.
08-26 12:07:58.219: DEBUG/Home(2350): Rathod -- RathoD
08-26 12:07:58.229: DEBUG/Home(2350): No. of differences : 2
08-26 12:07:58.229: DEBUG/Home(2350): Files are not equal

**Edit**

### To get Difference between two files

Use **[StringUtils](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/maven2/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.4/commons-lang-2.4.jar)** library which is provide by Apache and check this **[Documentation](http://www.as3commons.org/as3-commons-lang/asdoc/org/as3commons/lang/StringUtils.html)** for more about that library.

And modify following lines of code.

```
int x = 0;
for (int m = 0; m < a.length; m++) {
    if (a[m].equals(b[m])) {
    } else {
        x++;
        Log.d("Home", a[m] + " -- " + b[m]);
        //to print difference   
        if (a[m].length() < b[m].length())
            Log.d("Home", "" + StringUtils.difference(a[m], b[m]));
        else
            Log.d("Home", "" + StringUtils.difference(b[m], a[m]));
    }       
}
```

**Output**

08-26 17:51:26.949: DEBUG/Home(17900): 12 -- 123
08-26 17:51:26.949: DEBUG/Home(17900): Difference String : 3
08-26 17:51:26.949: DEBUG/Home(17900): No. of differences : 1
08-26 17:51:26.949: DEBUG/Home(17900): Files are not equal

Comment: Thank u.. But let me ask u that this code works when same data in both files are in random order?

Comment: @AnilBhatiya, I edited by answer and output also. Though your data are not in order, this will work. You can check by my output in answer.

Comment: And one more thing, line by lines means, first line with first line of second file. Such comparison is there. This will not provide you first line compare with whole file then second with whole file.

Comment: @AnilBhatiya, I added my code for line separator. Its working fine now. Please review that.

Comment: Hey I tried ur code but it hangs my app... when i click on button to make comparison, app hangs and shows no output...

Comment: @AnilBhatiya, Then just low down that 10000 to 1000 in code and then try again. And may i know how big your files are.??

Comment: They are small i size

Comment: They are names ...means Strings...What I have to do here is to read names of facebook friend list and store them in one file...and compare them with another files wich contains data of same/different names..

Comment: @AnilBhatiya I don't know why code is hangs on.. Because I have tried code, and i also put my output which is of logs and of-course not my home made :).. Have you tried my edited answer or you have tried first one?

Comment: @ Chintan Rathod : It's working but I want only those data which are not in second file.

Comment: Let's say in file1, data are 1,2,3 and in file 2 data are 1,2. Now I want only 3 as output...

Comment: ya I tried 

String h = StringUtils.difference(a[m], b[m]).toString();

Comment: else {
        x++;
        Log.d("Home", a[m] + " -- " + b[m]);
        //to print difference   
        if (a[m].length() < b[m].length())
            Log.d("Home", "" + StringUtils.difference(a[m], b[m]));
        else
            Log.d("Home", "" + StringUtils.difference(b[m], a[m]));
    }

Comment: I put toast message to check whether this executes or not, but it's not

Comment: if (a[m].length() < b[m].length())
               {
                Log.d("Home", "" + StringUtils.difference(a[m], b[m]));
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),  "One :" + StringUtils.difference(a[m], b[m]), 1000).show();
               }
                   
               else
               {
                Log.d("Home", "" + StringUtils.difference(b[m], a[m]));
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),  "Two :" + StringUtils.difference(b[m], a[m]), 1000).show();
               }

Comment: can u come in chat window

Comment: You need to pass `YOUR_ACTIVITY_NAME.this` instead of `getBaseContext()`. Please do that changes. I implement your code posted in comment with modification which i said. It displays output.

Comment: still no output broda

Answer (score 1):

Try using  `java.util.Scanner`

```
  while (sc1.hasNext() && sc2.hasNext()) {
        String str1 = sc1.next();
        String str2 = sc2.next();
        if (!str1.equals(str2))
            System.out.println(str1 + " != " + str2);
    }
```

Comment: If they have unequal lines, at the end of your logic above it can be assumed that both files are same!

Comment: @MT8...It's working fine when data are in order...means here in file1 data are 1,2,3,4 and in file2 data are 1,2. But if I change the content like in file1 data are 1,2,3 and in file data are 3,2 then it's not showing any results.

Comment: But can you guarantee the precondition? It is always best to avoid making unnecessary assumptions. The less assumptions you make, the safer your code is. ( I know I am overgeneralising! )

Answer (score 0):

Change your while loop to the following:

```
while (scanFile.hasNextLine() && scanFileT.hasNextLine())
{
    if(scanFileT.nextLine().equals(scanFile.nextLine()))
    {
        // The lines are equal.
    } else {
        // The lines are not equal.
    }
}

if(scanFile.hasNextLine() || scanFileT.hasNextLine())
{
    // If more lines remain in one of the files, they are not equal.
} else {
    // If no content remains in both files, they are equal.
}
```

Depending on the size of your file, I would recommend some optimisation like checking the file sizes before you go through them line by line.

The overall logic reads as follows; if both have another line, compare it to see if it is equal. If they don't have another line, check if one of them has lines remaining, if so, they are not equal.

**Update**
After clarifying the objective of the comparison in chat, see the comments to this question, I have come to the conclusion that another comparison would be more effective and, as a matter of fact, correct. The comparison algorithm above works great if comparing the structure of text but not if comparing a data vector which may or may not be sorted. After some discussion, we came to the conclusion that data needs to be sorted or the comparison will blow the complexity to at least `O(n^2)`which could be done in `O(2n)` if the data is sorted. Here the algorithm's skeleton:

```
if(! scanGroupFriends.hasNextLine())
{
    //simple sanity check to see if we need to compare at all. In this case, add all friends.
} else {
    String nextFriend = scanGroupFriends.nextLine();

    while(scanAllFriends.hasNextLine())
    {
        if(scanAllFriends.nextLine().equals(nextFriend))
        {
            // Friend already figures, do not add him and advance the list of group friends.
            if(scanGroupFriends.hasNextLine())
            {
                nextFriend = scanGroupFriends.nextLine();
            } else {
                // There are no more friends in the group, add all remaining friends to list to show.
                break; // Terminate the `while` loop.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, I personally think it is bad to make to many assumptions. What I would suggest is that the friends be saved in a `Set`, a `TreeSet` for example. Then, serialize the object rather than manually writing it to file. Sets are neat because they hold several interesting objects. For example, you could easily use the following code to remove all friends in a group from the set of all friends:

```
allFriends.removeAll(groupFriends);
```

However, be aware that this removes it from the set completely so you should make a copy beforehand.

Comment: Could you be more specific please? The snippet above is meant to be completed. Put your logic where my comments are.

Comment: while (scanFile.hasNextLine())
    {
        if(scanFile.hasNextLine() && scanFileT.hasNextLine())
        {
            if(scanFileT.nextLine().equals(scanFile.nextLine()))
            {
                   countThree++;
            } 
            else 
            {
               
            }
        } 
        else {
            
        }
        }

Comment: My apologies for the copy-paste error. I edited the solution.

Comment: It's working fine when data are in order...means here in file1 data are 1,2,3,4 and in file2 data are 1,2. But if I change the content like in file1 data are 1,2,3 and in file data are 3,2 then it's not showing any results.

Comment: In that case the `while` will terminate early and the `if` clause after the `while` will return `true`. You need to handle cases of inequality there.

Comment: @ Eric Tobias..hey thanks for ur answers but the answer which u have suggested in last comment, i don't get it....

Comment: The `while` will finish if one of the two files runs out of lines. The `if` after the `while` will check if one of the `Scanner` instances has lines left to iterate over. If that is the case, you know that they are not equal.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36226/discussion-between-eric-tobias-and-anil-bhatiya)